# VSCode: CTRL+Right Arrow fires cursorWorkEndRight but then is is converted to cursorWordLeft

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this issue that only happens when I type CTRL+Right Arrow after a word that begins with a period. For example, if my cursor is at the capital S here:

```
if (data && data.SecretString) {
```

I see the cursor flash to the end of the word, and immediately jumps back to the beginning of the word.

How do I stop the final result of cursorWordLeft?

[Output from Palette tool:: Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting]

```
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlRight, keyCode: 17, key: Control
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlRight, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowRight, keyCode: 39, key: ArrowRight
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowRight, keyCode: 17 ('RightArrow')
| Resolving alt+[ArrowRight]
\ From 3 keybinding entries, matched cursorWordEndRight, when: textInputFocus, source: built-in.
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowRight, keyCode: 39, key: ArrowRight
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowRight, keyCode: 17 ('RightArrow')
| Resolving alt+[ArrowRight]
\ From 3 keybinding entries, matched cursorWordEndRight, when: textInputFocus, source: built-in.
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowLeft, keyCode: 37, key: ArrowLeft
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: ArrowLeft, keyCode: 15 ('LeftArrow')
| Resolving alt+[ArrowLeft]
\ From 3 keybinding entries, matched cursorWordLeft, when: textInputFocus, source: built-in.
+ Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.
+ Clearing single modifier due to 300ms elapsed.
```

Per [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64972) I added this to keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u001bb"
    },
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u001bf"
    },
}
```

EDIT: I'm on a Mac

Comment: Also tried:     {
        "key": "ctrl+left",
        "command": "cursorWordeft",
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+right",
        "command": "cursorWordRight",
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` search for `cursorWordLeft` and make sure this is not bound to the same key or unbind it (click on it and then press delete on your keyboard). You can try setting up everything from there instead of using the json file.